# Show that $\phi$ is an isomorphism in this double quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, quotient-spaces, ring-isomorphism

I want to know if the following is true and if so, then how to prove it:

Let $x,y$ be distinct elements of a ring $A$ and let $\langle x \rangle $, $\langle x,y \rangle $, etc. be the ideals generated by $\{x\}$, $\{x,y\}$, etc.

Let $\pi_1,\pi_2, p$ be the canonic projections to the quotient rings as shown in the diagram below and let $\pi=\pi_2\circ\pi_1$

[image]

I want to show (if true) that $\phi$ is an isomorphism. By the iso. theorem it would suffice to show that $\langle x,y \rangle = \ker(\pi) $ and that $\pi$ is surjective  (for then $\phi$'s existance is guaranteed and $A/\ker(\pi)\cong \text{Im}(\phi)$).

---

I tried this:

Take $z\in \langle x,y \rangle$ then $z=ax+by$ with $a,b\in A$ then $\pi_1(z)=\overline{by}$ then $\pi_2(z)=\overline{\bar{b}\bar{y}}=\overline{\bar{0}}$ thus $z\in \ker(\pi)$.

Take $z\in \ker(\pi)$ then $\overline{\bar{z}}=\overline{\bar{0}}$ then $\bar z = \bar b \bar y$ for some $\bar b\in A/\langle x\rangle$ then $z=ax+b'y$ for some $a\in A, b'\in \bar b$ thus $z\in \langle x,y \rangle$.

Therefore $\ker(\pi)=\langle x, y\rangle$.

Take $w\in A/\langle x\rangle \big{/} \langle \bar y \rangle$ then there exists $v\in A/\langle x\rangle $ such that $w =\overline{v}$ and there exists $u\in A$ such that $\bar u =v$ thus $\pi(u)=\overline{\bar{u}} =w$.

Therefore $\pi$ is surjective.

---

I am not entirely convinced by this proof, specially by the $\ker(\pi)\subseteq \langle x,y\rangle $ part.

Is what I've done right? Is there another way to prove it?

Thanks in advance for any help whatsoever.

---

P.S. I donk know why the picture of the diagram is blurry, I uploaded it as a HQ PNG.

Comment: Your proof looks good. However, you could use the general information that quotient maps are always subjective as they are projection maps. In addition to that you could use the homomorphism theorem. This would immediately lead to $\ker(\pi_1)=\langle x\rangle$ and $\ker(\pi_2)=\langle \bar{y} \rangle$ resulting in $\ker(\pi) = \langle \ker(\pi_1), \pi_1^{-1}(\ker(\pi_2))\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle$

Comment: Thanks, if by the hom. theorem you mean what you wrote after that then I didn't know that. I mean, it's similar to what you see in linear algebra for transformations  but this one in particular I didn't know. Thanks again!

Comment: The hom. theorem in this case is as follows: We take $f:A \to A, x \to 0$. If we use the hom. theorem we get that $f(A)\simeq A/\langle x\rangle$, because we chose the function to have $\ker(f)=\langle x \rangle$. The formula for $\ker(\pi)$ is then derived by composition of $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$

Comment: Note that in general if $J$ contains $I$ then the map $A/I \to A/J$ sending an element to its class induces an isomorphism $(A/I)/(J/I) \to A/J$ . This is usually called the Noether's third isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Thank you, that's quite elegant.